# Замена цикла на стандартный алгоритм

Tags: c++

Можно ли заменить следующий цикл на какой-то стандартный алгоритм библиотеки?

```
for (auto iterator = a.begin() + x; iterator != a.end() - y; ++iterator) {
    *(iterator + y) = f(*iterator, *(iterator + y));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навскидку

```
std::transform(a.begin() + x, a.end() - y, a.begin() + x + y, a.begin() + x + y, f);
```

Однако `std::transform`, насколько я помню, не гарантирует порядка обработки элементов. Так как такая операция потенциально может модифицировать входной диапазон, непредсказуемый порядок обработки может привести к непредсказуемым результатам. То есть проблема возникает если диапазон `[a.begin() + x, a.end() - y)` перекрывается с диапазоном `[a.begin() + x + y, a.end())`.

Comment: Да, в этом и проблема. Я прочитал на `cppreference` написано, что `unary_op and binary_op must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, or modify any elements of the ranges involved.`

Comment: Причём `for_each` тоже не могу, потому что непонятно как узнать итератор, отстоящий на `y` и reduce/accumulate не могу (y=1 на самом деле), потому что тоже не могут инвалидировать

Comment: @bipol: Не понял. При чем здесь эта цитата? `std::transform` *всегда* модифицирует выходную последовательность. В этом заключается назначение `std::transform`, по определению. Процитированное вами требование этим никак не нарушается. Процитированное вами требование запрещает выполнять эти модификации *внутри* вашего `f`. Но вы этого и не делаете внутри вашего `f`, так? Тогда причем здесь эта цитата?

Comment: Стоп, то есть трансформ может модифицировать элементы по которым ходит, главное чтобы функция их не модифицировала?

Comment: Именно так. И проблем здесь нет, пока `[a.begin() + x, a.end() - y)` не перекрывается с `[a.begin() + x + y, a.end())`. Как только они начнут перекрываться, результат будет зависеть от порядка обработки в `std::transform`. А это уже большая проблема, с формальной точки зрения.

Comment: Ну они перекрываются, у меня x = a.size()/2, а y=1. Т.е. хочу обработать так половину массива

Comment: На самом деле обнаружил, что мне необязательно делать это внутри контейнера. Можно сделать копию, а потом `std::move`, т.к. всё равно этот модифицированный контейнер передаётся в другую функцию. Спасибо за пояснения по трансформу!

Comment: @bipol std::for_each - не модифицирующая , std::transform - модифицирующая

Comment: @Beeen007: `std::for_each` как раз таки разрешается модифицировать элементы контейнера внутри функтора.

Comment: @AnT только если они передаются в функтор по ссылке,  но в for_each обычно кидают элементы как конст ссылку, но да такая возможность есть. ссылка все-же